# Column 'DEV_EIMDW_BOJ_REPORTS.dbo.bojdeposit_tab.CUSTOMER_ID' is invalid in the select list

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

I'm trying to do an insertion using a procedure that creates the table and populate it. The error is:
Column 'DEV_EIMDW_BOJ_REPORTS.dbo.bojdeposit_tab.CUSTOMER_ID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

```
INSERT INTO 
  dbo.PortfolioTable(custIdTrn,portfolioValue,scheme_type,jmdvalue,jmdeq,usdeq,usdvalue,cadvalue,gbpvalue,eurvalue,usdoth) 
  select trn,portfolio_size, scheme_type, sum(jmdval), sum(jmdeq),sum(usdeq),
  sum(usdvalue), sum(cadvalue), sum(gbpvalue), sum(eurvalue),sum(usdoth) 
  from 
    (  SELECT
      CASE WHEN b.trn IS NULL THEN  b.customer_id ELSE b.trn END AS trn,
      p.portfolio_size,
      b.scheme_type,
      case currency when 'JMD' then  transaction_balance  else 0 end jmdval, 
      case currency when 'JMD' then 0 else dbo.FN_ConvertAmountAsOfDate(@asAtDate, currency,'JMD',transaction_balance,'REV') end jmdeq,
      case currency  when 'JMD' then 0 else dbo.FN_ConvertAmountAsOfDate(@asAtDate, currency,'USD',transaction_balance,'REV') end usdeq,
      case currency when 'USD' then transaction_balance else 0 end usdvalue ,
      case currency when 'CAD' then transaction_balance else 0 end cadvalue ,
      case currency when 'GBP' then transaction_balance else 0 end gbpvalue ,       
      case currency when 'EUR' then transaction_balance else 0 end eurvalue ,       
      case currency  when 'JMD' then 0 when 'USD' then 0 when 'CAD' then 0 when 'GBP' then 0 when 'EUR' then 0 
       else dbo.FN_ConvertAmountAsOfDate(@asAtDate, currency,'USD',transaction_balance,'REV') end usdoth 
      FROM
      [DEV_EIMDW_BOJ_REPORTS].[dbo].[bojdeposit_tab] b
      INNER JOIN
      [DEV_EIMDW_BOJ_REPORTS].[dbo].[BOJ_DEPOSIT_PORTFOLIO] p
      ON
      b.customer_id = p.cust_id
      WHERE
      NOT EXISTS  (SELECT 1 FROM boj_deposits_exclusion e where e.acid  = b.acid)
      AND borrower_category_code IN (SELECT VALUE FROM string_split((SELECT borrowercat_code FROM M11_CATEGORY WHERE description = 'BUSFIRMS'),','))
      AND sector_code IN (SELECT VALUE FROM string_split((SELECT sector_code FROM M11_CATEGORY WHERE description = 'BUSFIRMS'),','))
      AND sub_sector_code IN (SELECT VALUE FROM string_split((SELECT sub_sector_code FROM M11_CATEGORY WHERE description = 'BUSFIRMS'),','))
      AND not EXISTS (SELECT acid from [DEV_EIMDW_Archive].[ARCHOWN].[FINCL_ALR] WHERE acct_label  IN ('MUNDO', 'BOJCAMBIO', 'VOSTROACCT') AND acid = b.acid)
      AND b.borrower_category_code != '500'
      group by trn,portfolio_size, scheme_type
      ) AS Portfolio
```

Comment: Google how to use `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Please, include a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All  columns that are **not involved** in aggregations has to be specified in a `GROUP BY` clause. In fact, the original query has a correct `GROUP BY`, but it was placed to a wrong line and has to be moved outside.

**Adjusted query:**

```
INSERT INTO 
dbo.PortfolioTable(custIdTrn,portfolioValue,scheme_type,jmdvalue,jmdeq,usdeq,usdvalue,cadvalue,gbpvalue,eurvalue,usdoth) 
select trn,portfolio_size, scheme_type, sum(jmdval), sum(jmdeq),sum(usdeq),
sum(usdvalue), sum(cadvalue), sum(gbpvalue), sum(eurvalue),sum(usdoth) 
from 
(  SELECT
    CASE WHEN b.trn IS NULL THEN  b.customer_id ELSE b.trn END AS trn,
    p.portfolio_size,
    b.scheme_type,
    case currency when 'JMD' then  transaction_balance  else 0 end jmdval, 
    case currency when 'JMD' then 0 else dbo.FN_ConvertAmountAsOfDate(@asAtDate, currency,'JMD',transaction_balance,'REV') end jmdeq,
    case currency  when 'JMD' then 0 else dbo.FN_ConvertAmountAsOfDate(@asAtDate, currency,'USD',transaction_balance,'REV') end usdeq,
    case currency when 'USD' then transaction_balance else 0 end usdvalue ,
    case currency when 'CAD' then transaction_balance else 0 end cadvalue ,
    case currency when 'GBP' then transaction_balance else 0 end gbpvalue ,       
    case currency when 'EUR' then transaction_balance else 0 end eurvalue ,       
    case currency  when 'JMD' then 0 when 'USD' then 0 when 'CAD' then 0 when 'GBP' then 0 when 'EUR' then 0 
    else dbo.FN_ConvertAmountAsOfDate(@asAtDate, currency,'USD',transaction_balance,'REV') end usdoth 
    FROM
    [DEV_EIMDW_BOJ_REPORTS].[dbo].[bojdeposit_tab] b
    INNER JOIN
    [DEV_EIMDW_BOJ_REPORTS].[dbo].[BOJ_DEPOSIT_PORTFOLIO] p
    ON
    b.customer_id = p.cust_id
    WHERE
    NOT EXISTS  (SELECT 1 FROM boj_deposits_exclusion e where e.acid  = b.acid)
    AND borrower_category_code IN (SELECT VALUE FROM string_split((SELECT borrowercat_code FROM M11_CATEGORY WHERE description = 'BUSFIRMS'),','))
    AND sector_code IN (SELECT VALUE FROM string_split((SELECT sector_code FROM M11_CATEGORY WHERE description = 'BUSFIRMS'),','))
    AND sub_sector_code IN (SELECT VALUE FROM string_split((SELECT sub_sector_code FROM M11_CATEGORY WHERE description = 'BUSFIRMS'),','))
    AND not EXISTS (SELECT acid from [DEV_EIMDW_Archive].[ARCHOWN].[FINCL_ALR] WHERE acct_label  IN ('MUNDO', 'BOJCAMBIO', 'VOSTROACCT') AND acid = b.acid)
    AND b.borrower_category_code != '500'
   -- the line below was commented out, because it should be stated outside!
   -- group by trn,portfolio_size, scheme_type
) AS Portfolio
-- Moved outside from the inner query:
GROUP BY trn,portfolio_size, scheme_type
```

Comment: will the OP's query work if theres customer_id added to `group by` in the subquery? I mean i guess it should in case statements but this is a wild guess and might led to bad behaviour of the querie's o/p not sure

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja, that GROUP BY clause inside of a derived query has to be moved outside. It was placed there by mistake and it is actually a reason why initial query of OP fails. Just check once more a query, it has no aggregations like SUM or COUNT in the inner query.

Comment: Spot on @Alexander Volok, Actually my bad I did not read the full query earlier you are correct that group by is relating to outer query not inner query and the fact that aggregations are involved as well in the outer query. Thanks :)

Comment: @DavidSmith, since you issue is addressed can you consider mark your question as answered?